# Why is Oracle database tables getting deleted when i close the run sql command line prompt?

Tags: sql, oracle

All the tables data is getting deleted when shutting down the run sql and command line. Also there is only one user.

Answer (score 2):

i think, that you are missing `commit;` Check out Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT037

Comment: exactly .....................